# How would one pass a component to a helper?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, helper

I want to pass a component to a helper and have that helper return an array of objects, each with a component node...

```
// helpers.ts
import { LINKS } from '../constants';
// error on the next line: Cannot find name 'Component'. ts(2304)
const createLinks = (component: Component) => {
  return LINKS.map((props) => {
    return ({
      content: <Component {...props} />,
      id: props.id
    });
  });
};
```

```
// component.tsx
import { List, SpecialLink } from '../components';
import { createLinks } from '../helpers';
const LinkList = () => {
  const links = createLinks(SpecialLink);
  return <List items={links}>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `ComponentType` type of `react`, so the component argument can be class component or function component.

```
type ComponentType<P = {}> = ComponentClass<P> | FunctionComponent<P>;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { ComponentType } from 'react';

const LINKS: any[] = [];
const createLinks = (Component: ComponentType) => {
  return LINKS.map((props) => {
    return {
      content: <Component {...props} />,
      id: props.id,
    };
  });
};
```